# How can I load animated .gif file in shader resource view in Directx11?

Tags: c++, directx-11, animated-gif

How can I load animated .gif file in an array of ID3D11ShaderResourceView on Directx11?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What did I do wrong?

Comment: Read the link I've given and you'll understand.

Comment: " what details can you include that will help someone identify and solve your problem", "Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Imaging Component (WIC) can load the individual 'raw frames' from an animated gif, but you have to compose them with the help of extra metadata. I recently implemented a mode in the [DirectTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) tool `texassemble` that creates a 2D texture array `DDS` flipbook from an animated gif. You can either use it as an offline solution (convert to `DDS`, then use [DDSTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DDSTextureLoader) to load it at runtime), -or- review the code for an example of doing it yourself.

See [texassemble.cpp](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/master/Texassemble/texassemble.cpp) and look at the function `LoadAnimatedGif`.

Comment: The "output" of LoadAnimatedGif() is loadedImages, isn't it? For dds, have I to use CreateDDSTextureFromMemory()?

Comment: The purpose of the helper function is just to build an array of image data. You can save it to disk as a ``DDS`` such as I do in the tool, or you create textures directly from the image data. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476905.aspx)

Comment: I have a problem, when I compile the code I get some unresolved external symbol errors. Errors are here: https://github.com/Masesasso/Gif/blob/master/Error.PNG. Code is here: https://github.com/Masesasso/Gif/blob/master/Gif.cpp. How can I fix?

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Read the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/DirectXTex#adding-to-a-vs-solution)